# How to capture changing "authenticity_token" at run time using Jmeter's "Regular Expression Extractor"?

Tags: regex, jmeter, authenticity-token

I have tried to put `input\s+name=”authenticity_token”\s+type=”hidden”\s+value=”(.*?)”\s*\` in `Jmeter's Regular Expression Extractor` but that is not helping and test fails. For `Template` I kept `$1$` always.

On viewing source of page it was written like this:
`<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="OzzoQsvruAetQAiAMj5Mh4L730w0PUxzoALcgT3dI+o=" />`
Based on above, how should I write contents for `Regualr Expression Extractor`

Please see pic below:

[image]

**Its Ruby on Rails application**

Comment: what's the difference? however I tried with `"` but it is still failing.

Comment: The first is a right double quote..you can see how these characters differ in [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/yM5kG3) (note the capture groups on the right side).

Comment: It was failing for first one then I changed it to `"`, and then it failed again.

Comment: Try [removing the trailing `\s*\.`](http://regex101.com/r/gM7cL4), if that doesn't work..then it is something with JMeter that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: like this ` input+name="authenticity_token"+type="hidden"+value="(.*?)"*\ `

Comment: No trailing `*` or backslash `\ `

Answer (score 3):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748

> You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML.

I would strongly recommend using one of the following:

1. [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
2. [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

Example configuration of above to match your hidden input value:

**CSS/JQuery**

- Reference Name: `token`
- CSS/JQuery Expression: `input[name=authenticity_token]`
- Attribute: `value`

**XPath**

- Use Tidy - tick (if your response isn't XML/XHTML compliant)
- Reference Name: `token`
- XPath Query: `//input[@name='authenticity_token']/@value`

If you still need to stick to Regular Expression Extractor, following configuration might help:

- Reference Name: `token`
- Regular Expression: `<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="(.+?)" />`
- Template: `$1$`

But it will be very sensitive and fragile i.e. in case of attributes different order, multiline layout, etc. I would recommend consider using above extractors instead.

Hope this helps.